# How to filter a tree like array by a specific field using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

This is my result tree which I want to filter by 'language_code' field

```
"theme_detail": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "parent_theme_id": null,
                "image_url": "no_image",
                "index_value": 1,
                "status": "active",
                "theme_detail": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "theme_id": 1,
                        "language_code": "bn",
                        "theme_name": "থিম 1",
                        "theme_subtitle": "থিম 1 উপশিরোনাম",
                        "status": "active"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "theme_id": 1,
                        "language_code": "en",
                        "theme_name": "Theme 1",
                        "theme_subtitle": "Theme 1 Subtitle",
                        "status": "active"
                    }
                ],
                "parent_recursive": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "parent_theme_id": 1,
                        "image_url": "no_image",
                        "index_value": 1,
                        "status": "active",
                        "theme_detail": [
                            {
                                "id": 5,
                                "theme_id": 2,
                                "language_code": "bn",
                                "theme_name": "থিম 2",
                                "theme_subtitle": "থিম 2 উপশিরোনাম",
                                "status": "active"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 2,
                                "theme_id": 2,
                                "language_code": "en",
                                "theme_name": "Theme 2",
                                "theme_subtitle": "Theme 2 Subtitle",
                                "status": "active"
                            }
                        ],
                        "parent_recursive": [
                            {
                                "id": 3,
                                "parent_theme_id": 2,
                                "image_url": "no_image",
                                "index_value": 1,
                                "status": "active",
                                "theme_detail": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 3,
                                        "theme_id": 3,
                                        "language_code": "en",
                                        "theme_name": "Theme 3",
                                        "theme_subtitle": "Theme 3 Subtitle",
                                        "status": "active"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 6,
                                        "theme_id": 3,
                                        "language_code": "bn",
                                        "theme_name": "থিম 3",
                                        "theme_subtitle": "থিম 3 উপশিরোনাম",
                                        "status": "active"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "parent_recursive": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 4,
                                        "parent_theme_id": 3,
                                        "image_url": "no_image",
                                        "index_value": 1,
                                        "status": "active",
                                        "theme_detail": [
                                            {
                                                "id": 7,
                                                "theme_id": 4,
                                                "language_code": "bn",
                                                "theme_name": "থিম 4",
                                                "theme_subtitle": "থিম 4 উপশিরোনাম",
                                                "status": "active"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "id": 9,
                                                "theme_id": 4,
                                                "language_code": "en",
                                                "theme_name": "Theme 4",
                                                "theme_subtitle": "Theme 4 Subtitle",
                                                "status": "active"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "parent_recursive": []
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 5,
                                "parent_theme_id": 2,
                                "image_url": "no_image",
                                "index_value": 1,
                                "status": "active",
                                "theme_detail": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 8,
                                        "theme_id": 5,
                                        "language_code": "bn",
                                        "theme_name": "থিম 5",
                                        "theme_subtitle": "থিম 5 উপশিরোনাম",
                                        "status": "active"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 10,
                                        "theme_id": 5,
                                        "language_code": "en",
                                        "theme_name": "Theme 5",
                                        "theme_subtitle": "Theme 5 Subtitle",
                                        "status": "active"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "parent_recursive": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

---

This is my json array which is in a tree like structure.
This array is the result of a recursive eloquent relation.
Now I want to filter it by a specific language code or by any other field. 
How can I do it using Laravel eloquent?
can anybody help?

Comment: can you show the Eloquent Orm query ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46708457/how-to-pass-parameter-from-controller-to-model-in-case-of-recursion. This is a link where I have already posted my model and controller. Please check it. If it can be solved in the eloquent ORM level then it would be more helpful for me.

Comment: Will you be getting the array of `language_code` or you will be geting single code ?

Comment: I have added an answer kindly check it.

Comment: the langiuage_code is a single variable not an array

Comment: Do you want to find `language_code` in your result, or do you want to do the query?

Comment: What would be your expected result? to show same result but only with `language_code`? what if parent doesn't have language, but child has that language?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your eventual response to be like this:

```
'language_code' => [item_list]
```

Comment: I want the whole array with a specific language_code

Comment: you need to Collections filter method in this regard for `theme_detail` & `parent_recursive`. However looking at the structure of json array, it is quite frankly incredibly complex. You need to simplify it first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46708457/how-to-pass-parameter-from-controller-to-model-in-case-of-recursion. Please check out this link where I have posted my model and controller. Can you please simplify it?